# Space requirements of softwares installed on external hard disks

Tags: windows-8.1, external-hard-drive

If I install a software on an external hard disk does it sill uses some space of the main internal hard disk where my Windows 8.1 OS is installed?

I mean if I have for example a 50 Gb SSD internal hard disk where I installed Windows 8.1 and I have a 1 Tb USB 3.0 external hard drive, then if I would install for example 5-6 softwares on the external hard disk which all take at least 10 Gb+ space would it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on the software itself, but in general the software installation will not use any space on the OS drive. Many softwares however will put some files in your user profile which by default is on the same drive as your OS.

Comment: Also, the registry and %windir%\installer, and %windir%\WinSxS, etc. :)

Comment: So your saying most of the data will be on the external drive, like 90%+. Like at a game saved games might be saved into my internal hard drive where my documents at, but that is not too much, right?

Comment: It varies greatly from product to product, but essentially.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will mark it as solved and I guess I just gonna try it out in practice!